# Шифрование строки на сервере, дешифрование на SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Задача состоит в том, что необходимо реализовать 1 метод шифрования/дешифрования строки как на C# так и на MSSQL, так как данные будут передаваться в БД и должны там храниться в зашифрованном виде.
Какие методы шифрования можно использовать что бы их можно было реализовать на MSSQL?

Comment: Ну, будут храниться, а при доставании оттуда через C# обратно можете расшифровывать. Или нужно доставать обратно из БД не только через C#? Насколько я помню, в MS SQL можно писать процедуры прямо на C#, но подробностей не знаю.

Comment: Ну так смотрите документацию на Вашу СУБД - какие методы и алгоритмы шифрования там поддержаны, и что из этого можно реализовать в программе на шарпее. Какие сложности-то?

Comment: В вопросе не указано, что за SQL используется, поэтому слишком абстрактно. Разные SQL - разные возможности, на вопрос не ответить.

Comment: Используется MSSQL, С# библиотеки не будет возможности использовать, так как огромное приложение, в документации только стандартные методы шифрования которые непонятно как реализовать на C#

Comment: Осталось понять зачем нужно что-то дешифровывать на SQL. Не очень ясен смысл такого шифрования…

Comment: @AlexeyTen Клиент требует. Шифровать и Дешифровать надо и на C#, но дешифровать только на MSSQL. Зачем? Кто бы знал, Видимо где то там еще эти данные будут использоваться

Comment: чтобы отладка была веселее, зачем еще)

Comment: Типичный стек. Зайти, сказать что вопрос не правильный, понаставить друг другу плюсиков и как получили объяснение срулить. Гениально. Ответ нашёл...

Comment: @Unnamed напишите найденное решение в ответе на вопрос и сделаете стек лучше

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное решение из коробки - использовать фичу [Always Encrypted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)